# SaaS subscription across iOS, Android and Web

Tags: developer-program, in-app-purchase

We have three different forms of distribution for our SaaS (Web, Android and iOS) all currently reviewed and in-store in their free form ($0).

Our business model is focussed around a single subscription across all platforms and was hoping to use our existing system of Stripe > Webhook to updates all services of a users status.

Heads down in the development has overlooked the very confusing, constantly changing and expensive (70/30 split!) guidelines that Apple publishes.

We've developed blindly as looking at apps like Dropbox and many others offer the same subscription / account across all platforms.

My questions is how are they doing it? IAP? External subscription? From the guidelines you are not allowed to link to a 'Buy / Subscribe' button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allowed to *link* to an external payment method, but saying that the app requires payment outside of the app is fine.

For example, mentioning in the app description that the app “requires a valid subscription to *x*” is acceptable, whereas having a link inside the app to “purchase your subscription here” is not unless that purchase is through IAP.

Comment: Well I would vote this up if I had enough rep... seems SO doesn't carry over to here...

Comment: @Taylorsuk Thanks; once you earn 200 reputation somewhere, you get a bonus of 100 everywhere else.

Comment: Ok need 4 more on SO then I'm good :) cheers

Comment: @Taylorsuk There you go then :)

Comment: Nice...another 44k to catch you!